# How to replace at a specific position in a string using vba

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I would to replace one value in a string of text file.
If I try the replace that value with Replace method, all same values get replaced.
I just want to replace the one at specific position in the string.

Example
00, 0, 0 => 00, 1, 0 (OK)
00, 0, 0 => 11, 1, 1 (not)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hera are 4 different ways to replace `0` with `1`. But only two are usable in your case.

1. [WorksheetFunction.Replace()](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/replace.php)

   `WorksheetFunction.Replace( old_text, start, number_of_chars, new_text )`
2. [WorksheetFunction.Substitute()](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/substitute.php)

   `WorksheetFunction.Substitute(text, oldtext, newtext, [nth_appearance] )`
3. <strike>[Replace()](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/replace_vba.php)</strike>

   `Replace( Expression, Find, Replace, [Start, [Count, [Compare]]] )`
4. <strike>[Range.Replace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194086.aspx)</strike>

   `Range.Replace( What, Replacement, [LookAt], [SearchOrder], [MatchCase], [SearchFormat], [ReplaceFormat] )`

```
Input        VBA code                                      Output
```

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for answer.
I have developed using Split and Join Function.

Code:

Dim Arr() As String
Arr = Split("00, 0, 0", ",")
Arr(1) = "1"
newLine = Join(Arr, ",")          'It becomes "00, 1, 0"